# LinkedIn Profile PlugIn does not load logo #linkedin

Tags: plugins, linkedin-api, profile

I've been dealing with an issue regarding the LinkedIn Company Profile Plugin, using the following code:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
```

Which  was provided in this page https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile I'm able to embed the profile but the company logo just does not seem to load and uppon inspection its throwing a 404 error on the logo resource.

[image]

I must note that this also happens in the above mentioned page, with different browsers and logged in users.

If there is a #linkedin Dev/Admin out there it would be helpful to clarify is this a problem on their side, thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

so i check and i found out that the image they had in the example just does not exist anymore, here is an example with the image still intact.

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile

so probably your image is just invalid.

Comment: I noticed the image is throwing a 404 error when I inspect the sources in both Linked In and our company profile, however this is something we don't have control over since its generated by their embed code.

Comment: @SamuelLiew the problem is that linkedin support allways redirects people here. stating that people will help and that they probably will find an answer here. if you look at the last 5-10 questions with the tag linkedin. there are 5 people that come from linkedin support. and they will phrase their question like they send to the linkedin support and by that standard all those questions get -1's. i am trying to help those people out but many questions are getting put on hold or closed because all those new people do not get stacks standards.

Comment: Yeah we are aware of that.. unfortunately the only ones who can fix this isn't on Stack Overflow.